# Excel VBA calculate filtered cells and copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have 2 worksheets; Sheet1 for entering data for number of times a lamp is lit in a day (there are several lamps), and Sheet 2 is summary for total accumulated lit times of each lamp.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

My worker will update the data (i.e. Lamp ID and number of lit) in Sheet1 everyday. How do I calculate the total accumulated lit for each lamp in Sheet1 and then copy the value to Sheet2 via VBA? I am not sure how to communicate different worksheets...

Comment: VBA may be overkill for this. Look into the [SUMIF function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) for a conditional total of *Lit* based upon the *Lamp ID*.

Comment: Concur with @Jeeped... unless there is something else that isn't being mentioned, VBA is not the right tool for this job.  The built in excel formulas will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if needed in VBA on sheet2:

```
Sub test()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    i = 2 'start in row 2 with lamps
    While Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1))
    Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheet1.Range("A1:A9"), Sheet2.Cells(i, 1), Sheet1.Range("B1:B9"))
    i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: `i = i++` is not valid in VBA

Comment: while you are at it, you might like to close the While block

Comment: i am keep getting the run-time error 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error).

Comment: @katz works now. and thanks for helping out! did not know 'sumif' function previously, but now i do. =)